# PHP str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have the string $var in which I need to replace some text. The first "X" needs to be replaced by "A", the second "X" needs to be replaced by B and so on, here is an example:

```
<?php
$var = "X X X X"; // input
...
echo $var //the result: "A B C D"
?>
```

I tried with `str_replace` but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)'s `limit` argument to only replace once.

```
<?php
    $var = 'X X X X';
    $replace = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
    foreach($replace as $r)
        $var = preg_replace('/X/', $r, $var, 1);
    echo $var;
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ra9ulA

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
// as many as you think you'll need, maximum.
// this can be programmatically generated, if need be
$replacements = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'); // and so on    

function get_replace_value($matches) {
    global $replacements;
    return array_shift($replacements);
}

$var = preg_replace_callback("/" + preg_quote($needle) + "/",
    "get_replace_value", $var);
```

Comment: This would have been awesome, but it returns `Array Array Array Array` here

Comment: That doesn't work, instead of "A", "B", ... it just says "Array" 4 times, sorry

Comment: @Amber, the $replace as an array works only if the $search is an array too; else it's treated as a string.

Comment: And one more comment: the 4th (`$count`) argument of `str_replace` is a reference argument, so passing a "1" probably won't work.

Comment: There, edited to something that should work. And yes, you are correct @Brad; this is probably a sign I should be headed to sleep soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 'X X X X';
$replacements = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

$var = preg_replace_callback('/X/', function() use (&$replacements) {
    return array_shift($replacements);
}, $var);
```

---

Other solution:

```
$var = preg_replace('/X/', 'A', $var, 1);
$var = preg_replace('/X/', 'B', $var, 1);
$var = preg_replace('/X/', 'C', $var, 1);
$var = preg_replace('/X/', 'D', $var, 1);
```

This one uses the `$limit` parameter of preg_replace (we replace only one occurrence per call).

Comment: I like your solution with preg_replace_callback!

Answer (score 1):

Without use of regex

```
$arr = explode('X', 'X X X X');
$rep = array('A','B','C','D');
foreach ($arr as $idx=>$val)
{
  $arr[$idx] = $val.$rep[$idx];
}
echo implode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet one more solution (more for a dynamic number of Xs):

```
<?php

  $foo = 'X X X X X X';

  $Xs = preg_match_all('/\bX\b/',$foo,$_); if ($Xs === false) $Xs = 0;
  $alphabet = range('A', chr(64 + $Xs));
  foreach ($alphabet as $letter){
    $foo = preg_replace('/\bX\b/', $letter, $foo, 1);
  }

  echo $foo;
```

I also added the `\b` in to the pattern to only replace Xs that are free-standing, so "FAUX PAS X" only replaces the last X.

[demo](http://www.ideone.com/jHXqd)

[`alphabet_replace`](http://www.ideone.com/acwZt) (more modular form)

Answer (score 0):

Lets give it a shot, too, just for the heck of it ;)

```
$input = "X X X X";

function replace($input, array $replacements)
{
    $replacer = function(array &$i, array &$r, &$o) use(&$replacer) {
        if (count($i) === 0 || count($r) === 0) return;

        $i_cur = array_shift($i);

        if (ctype_space($i_cur)) $o .= $i_cur;
        else $o .= array_shift($r);

        $replacer($i, $r, $o);
    };

    $replacer(str_split($input), $replacements, $output);

    return $output;
}

var_dump(replace($input, range('A', 'Z')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of loops are happening in the other answers, here's an alternative.

```
$var = 'X X X X X X X';
$replace = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$var = preg_replace(array_fill(0, count($replace), '/X/'), $replace, $var, 1);
echo $var; // A B C D X X X
```