# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP str_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390289/php-str-replace)

I have a string $html in which there is the text `Greek` and `&nbsp;` multiple times. These need to be replaced by `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Gamma`, `Delta`, `Epsilon` in that order. Like this:

```
<?php
$html = "Greek blablabla &nbsp; Greek Greek blabla &nbsp;" //input
$html = "Alpha blablabla Beta Gamma Delta blabla Epsilon" //output
or
$html = "Greek blabla Greek Greek bla Greek Greek" //input
$html = "Alpha blabla Beta Gamma bla Delta Epsilon" //output
or
$html = "&nbsp; &nbsp; blablablabla &nbps; &nbsp; &nbsp;" //input
$html = "Alpha Beta blablablabla Gamma Delta Epsilon" //output
or ....
?>
```

It doesn't need to be solved with preg_replace but I think this is works best with it.

Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like you are following the same class than this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390289/php-str-replace :)

Comment: So you mean... it doesn't matter whatever somebody types, but if it's X or Y, it should be replaced by some ascii char?

Comment: @gieldl you are not forced to create a new account for each new question ;)

Comment: @Arnaud, I just made this account, the other question was as a guest

Comment: Looks like `$html = "A B C D E";` does what you need. (Hint: if it does not, your question lacks some detail.)

Comment: Why bother replacing anything if the output is always going to be the same?  Just output "A B C D E".

Comment: This answer (and others) also work with 5 or more replacements; just adapt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390289/php-str-replace/7390382#7390382

Comment: Are you required to use `preg_replace`?

Comment: @Tomalak, nope it's not that easy
I actually have a string of hundreds of characters which will be exploded into an array later

Comment: Arnaud, there are X's and Y's, that solution works when there are 5 X's but if there are 3 X's and 2 Y's, it's not going to work

Comment: Tomalak and Brad, as I said, this is an example, the actual string is much longer and complicated

Comment: As you can see in Jon's the answer, your "simplified" example is not sophisticated enough to represent your real problem.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short and to the point:

```
$input = '&nbsp; &nbsp; blablablabla &nbps; &nbsp; &nbsp;';

$replacements = array('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon');
$index = 0;
$result = preg_replace('/(Greek|&nbsp;)/e', '$replacements[$index++]', $input);

print_r($result);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/SC7Cg)**.

Comment: +1 for `/e`, which is often overlooked.

Comment: Aaaand another question answered the way it was asked. :-) +1 for putting up the mirror.

Comment: @Tomalak: To tell the truth, if this answer didn't present the opportunity to showcase `range` and the `/e` modifier, I would have abstained.

Comment: @Jon: Fair enough. Actually I think this answer should be accepted and the question re-asked. :)

Comment: What if I don't need A to Z but real words like Cat, Dog, Chicken, ... Will It work with arrays?

Comment: @gieldl: If I were in your shoes, I would go and read the documentation for [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to see why this works, and how. I would also read about `range`, because this is practically part of the input of `preg_replace`. If you understand why this works, you will be able to answer your other question yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the misunderstanding